# How do I.T. conferences record and synchronise video, audio and slides?

Tags: video, audio

Our company has been recently encouraging knowledge sharing via fortnightly presentations (usually on Powerpoint) with respect to tools, technologies and development methodologies. We would also like to record some of these presentations to allow for sharing between sites and to new starters.

I recently watched [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) and found the way the video triggers slide changes on the site to be a great way of accomplishing this.

Is there a definitive tool-stack that can be used to accomplish something like this? Or is this something we would need to develop in-house using a set of existing tools? How would you do it if you were going to start your own conference?

Answer (score 1):

It is a tall order because it requiters combining many different technologies however university I am studying at have this kind of service.
 
Here is their main website: https://vips.liedm.lt/en/ 
Here is an example https://vips.liedm.lt/vflash/klientas/2204/2207/false 
Check out recorded sessions to get controls in English there is menu call "Kalba" just click it and chose English controls will change to English.

It was developed on Drupal 6 and uses technologies like Flex and flash it uses wowza and red 5 for live video streaming.